# When exported the Texture of one Object missing

Tags: texturing, export

I downloaded this file online as fbx and blend file.

However when I try to export it into my Video editor, the textures of the plane are missing. The textures of the hangar are there strangely.
I tried to give it a new texture and export, but it is still missing.
Then I tried to export an fbx with clicking copy and adding the textures but didn’t work.
I also tried to export as fbx and put the textures with it together in a zip file but again the textures of the plane were missing.

What is the issue? I assume the creator didn’t had a nice folder structure but is it possible for me to link the texture to the object somehow?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: In addition to the above: try importing the FBX you made into Blender. If it works in Blender, then the issue is the video editor you use.